# Intersection of two int array in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the intersection of two int array . I am using this code :

```
  public int[] Find_Common_Elements(int[] p1, int[] p2)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < p1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < p2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (p1[i] == p2[j])
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        int[] result = new int[count];
        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < p1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < p2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (p1[i] == p2[j])
                {
                    result[count++] = p1[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public int[] BubbleSort(int[] numarray)
    {
        int max = numarray.Length;
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < max - i; j++)
            {

                if (numarray[j] > numarray[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = numarray[j];
                    numarray[j] = numarray[j + 1];
                    numarray[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return numarray;
    }

    public int[] Find_Unique_Elements(int[] numarray)
    {
        BubbleSort(numarray);
        int element = numarray[0];
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < numarray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (element == numarray[i])
                continue;
            else
            {
                element = numarray[i];
                count++;
            }
        }

        int[] result = new int[count];

        count = 0;
        element = numarray[0];
        result[count++] = element;
        for (int i = 1; i < numarray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (element == numarray[i])
                continue;
            else
            {
                element = numarray[i];
                result[count++] = element;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void Result()
    {
        int[] array1 = new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,
             95, 85, 75, 65, 55, 45, 35, 25, 15, 05,
             10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55
        };

        int[] array2 = new int[] { 15, 25, 35, 45, 55,
             12, 22, 32, 43, 52,
             15, 25, 35, 45, 55
        };

        int[] p1 = Find_Unique_Elements(array1);
        int[] p2 = Find_Unique_Elements(array2);
        int[] result = Find_Common_Elements(array1, array2);

        for (int i = 0; i < p1.Length; i++)
            textBox1.Text += "\n" + p1[i].ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < p2.Length; i++)
            textBox2.Text += "\n" + p2[i].ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            textBox3.Text += "\n"+result[i].ToString();
        }








    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Result();
    }
```

But the problem is that, the result obtained is 15 15 25 25 35 35 45 45 55 55 , and i want 15 25 35 45 55. what is the problem with this code ?
  Thanks for any help

Comment: why don't you return Find_Unique_Elements(result);

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the built-in Linq [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method for this:

```
using System.Linq; // Make sure you include this line

public int[] Find_Common_Elements(int[] p1, int[] p2)
{
    return p1.Intersect(p2).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Pop a `Distinct` on there, while you're at it -- based on the question, he wants the distinct intersection.

Comment: @DanielMann `Intersect` is a set operation, it will only return a set as a result, therefore there will never be duplicate items (unless you are using a different definition of equality for the distinct and the intersect).

Comment: @Servy I like that hat! I'd ask you how you got it, but I suppose then you'd have to kill me :p

Comment: Here I was thinking this must be some sort of homework where using intersect is not possible. Would still be interesting to see why the OPs code fails, as I cant find the error...

Comment: @p.s.w.g It's a secret hat (that I have no idea how I got).  I am rather proud of it though.

Comment: @hSchroedl Look carefully at the line that calls Find_Common_Elements.  :-)

Comment: @hSchroedl: The OP's code fails because his inner loop starts at 0 rather than at `i+1`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to solve the problem academically, i.e. not to use built-in methods, then here are the two solutions:

1. Sort both arrays. Then make a pass through them similar to Merge sort and print out elements that are equal.
2. Find a pivot in one array (e.g. using [Median of Medians](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=exercises/kth-smallest) algorithm). Then partition each array around that pivot. Then print out as many pivot values as there are in common in two arrays (by doing this you've resolved intersection of the pivot element). Then recursively repeat the operation on left partitions and on right partitions of the two arrays.

EDIT: I was puzzled by this problem from purely algorithmic point of view. Solution #2 is an optimized in-place intersection algorithm, but #1 works faster thanks to smaller constant factor. I've documented the differences and reasoning why sorting is much more efficient in an article, which is a little bit too long for this post: [Finding Intersection of Two Unsorted Arrays](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=exercises/array-intersection)

Answer (score 1):

Linq is definitely the cleanest way to do this, but that doesn't mean you should throw out your code.  It's a great learning tool to question "why doesn't this code do the same thing?"

The answer is remarkably simple.  You don't pass the unique arrays into `Find_Common_Elements`!  (`Find_Common_Elements` has a built-in assumption that the inputs have unique elements, otherwise the behavior would be as expected.)  Simply changing this

```
    int[] result = Find_Common_Elements(array1, array2);
```

to this:

```
    int[] result = Find_Common_Elements(p1, p2);
```

would have made your code work perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] one= { 1, 3, 4, 6, 7 };
        int[] second = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };

        foreach (int r in one.Intersect(second))
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

enjoy